# HTML, CSS Problem. td inside tr overflowing to the right

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to prevent **td** to overflow to the right inside **tr**. Instead I want to break it to new line when its content is growing but keep the whole content in one **tr**.

I've tried with width property but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm new to css, so I don't really know what else to do.

[image]

Comment: you should read carrefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you really need help and answers . Welcome on SO

Comment: Please help us help you by including your ode in the questionn

Answer (score 3):

Since the table has more content in one line than a screen monitor can fit, you might want to enable scrolling.

One option you could try is to enable scrolling for the `div.comicstable` container.

```css
.comicstable {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Or if you want to handle the scrolling manually using JavaScript, disable the overflow:

```css
.comicstable {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If you want your content to wrap if they are longer than a screen can display, you could try out the flex-box.

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox > div {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comicstable">
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x100">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See also:

- [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest in your case is to apply

```
.comicstable table tr td {
   /* ... previous code... */
   display: inline-block;
}
```

That will move TDs to the next line when there's no more width left.